# Distance between two cities

Tags: geometry

In a certain exercise I am asked to find the distance between Madrid and Hong Kong. I have been given the coordinates (latitude and longitude), but I don't know how to proceed.

- Madrid: $40.50^◦N, 3.67^◦W$
- Hong Kong: $22.28^◦N, 114.17 ^◦ E$

I have been given a formula regarding $arccos$, but I don't know what to do.

Comment: Tip: Think of it as on the spherical globe.

Comment: How to convert latitude-longitude coordinates to $(x,y,z)$ of a sphere centered in the origin)

Comment: No way answering this question without knowing the radius of the Earth :-)

Comment: What is the formula?

Comment: The radius I was given was $6371$ km

Comment: "I have been given a formula regarding arccos, but I don't know what to do."  Why didn't you include the formula?  Surely you realize that is the most important part of the question.

Comment: There are two interpretations of distance between points on the surface of a shpere: the shortest path along the surface of the sphere, or the straight-line distance through the body of the sphere. Probably the first interpretation is what is wanted here, but it doesn't hurt to make these things clear.

Comment: @DanielC.: please add all the information you have been given to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To calculate the distance between two points on the Earth given their latitude and longitude, you can use the haversine formula or the spherical law of cosines. Since you mentioned a formula regarding arccos (the inverse cosine function), we'll use the spherical law of cosines for this calculation.

The spherical law of cosines is given by:

$$d = r\arccos((\sin(lat_1)\sin(lat_2)) + (\cos(lat_1)\cos(lat_2)\cos(lon_2 - lon_1)))$$

Where:

- $d$ is the distance between the two points (along the surface of the sphere),
- $lat_1$ and $lat_2$ are the latitudes of the two points in radians,
- $lon_1$ and $lon_2$ are the longitudes of the two points in radians,
- $r$ is the radius of the Earth ($6371$ km)

Given the coordinates of Madrid and Hong Kong:

- Madrid: $40.50^\circ N, 3.67^\circ W$
- Hong Kong: $22.28^\circ N, 114.17^\circ E$

First, convert the coordinates from degrees to radians using the conversion $$\theta_{\text{radians}} = \theta_{\text{degrees}} \cdot \frac{\pi}{180}$$

- Madrid latitude in radians: $$lat_1= 40.50 \cdot \frac{\pi}{180}$$
- Madrid longitude in radians: $$lon_1 = -3.67 \cdot \frac{\pi}{180}$$ (negative because it's west)
- Hong Kong latitude in radians: $$lat_2 = 22.28 \cdot \frac{\pi}{180}$$
- Hong Kong longitude in radians: $$lon_2 = 114.17 \cdot \frac{\pi}{180}$$ (positive because it's east)

Now, substituting the radians we have into the spherical law of cosines:

$$d = 6371 \cdot \arccos(\sin\left(\frac{40.50 \times \pi}{180}\right) \cdot \sin\left(\frac{22.28 \times \pi}{180}\right) + \cos\left(\frac{40.50 \times \pi}{180}\right) \cdot \cos\left(\frac{22.28 \times \pi}{180}\right) \cdot \cos\left(\frac{114.17 \times \pi}{180} - \frac{-3.67 \times \pi}{180}\right))$$

$$=10532.9398062$$

So the distance between Madrid and Hong Kong $\approx$ $1.05\cdot 10^4$ km.

Can be confirmed with a quick google search of "Distance between Madrid and HK", which shows an answer of $10531$km

[image: Distance between madrid and hong kong]

Comment: Very didactic presentation.

Comment: The very small discrepancy (2 km) between your calculations and Google's calculation can be plainly explained by the fact that the longitude and latitude of Madrid given by OP differ from the ones I have found elsewere : 40.42 N and 3.704 W (airport in one case vs. city centre in the other ?)

Comment: I was given that one, but taking into account the surface of Madrid, there might be slight differences.